# why is this break not working? i should get [0,1] return not [0,1,1,0]

Tags: python-3.x, break

Dont know why it is returning [0,1,1,0] and not [0,1]

```
def TwoSum(nums,target):
        c = []
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            for j in range(0,len(nums)):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    c.append(i)
                    c.append(j)
                    break     
        return c  



print(TwoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` only stops the inner loop, if you want to immediately return, just use `return c`

please let me know if this works:

```py
def TwoSum(nums,target):
        c = []
        for i in range(0,len(nums)):
            for j in range(0,len(nums)):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    c.append(i)
                    c.append(j)
                    return c     
        return c  



print(TwoSum([2, 7, 11, 15], 9))
```

Comment: @MariusTrifan your loop should be up to `len(nums)-1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code, put simply, is that it scans (2, 7) twice: forwards and backwards.

First, it selects 2 in the outer for loop and finds that 7 works, because 2 + 7 = 9. Thus, it adds the positions of 2 and 7 to c. Now, c = [0, 1]

But then it selects 7 in the outer for loop and finds that 2 works, because 7 + 2 = 9. Thus, it adds the positions of 7 and 2 to c. Now, c = [0, 1, 1, 0]